# Dependent Add-on APK's

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hello I am trying to build a separate Add-on to my own existing Android Application.

I want this Add-on to be hidden on the android market if the user doesn't have the main app something like "uses-library". I tried using "uses-library" with my packagename of project 1 but the compiler simply says cannot install library does not exist! it is installed on the device. Do I have to add a shared library to the first projects manifest aswell? or am I completely off target!

Astro does this kind of thing with its pro, bluetooth and network modules.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that functionality is possible.

The android market does its own filtering to determine which Applications are shown to witch devices / users. As of now I don't believe that there are any public APIs for interacting with any of this functionality.

I've just double checked on my device without any Astro apps installed I can still see the Bluetooth and networking modules in the market if I search for the Astro Developer. So I think you are misunderstanding how they've deployed.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I have also been looking through it and other Apps appear to also show add-ons without the original being installed. I think the uses-library has confused me a-bit it seems only useful for the google maps! Thank you for your quick answer. Seems messy to have apps advertised which can't be used without first installing other apps is all.